# Infinite looping taking place and not able to update the form control value via global service and finally getting maximum stack size error

Tags: angular, bootstrap-datepicker, ngx-bootstrap, form-control

```
<input class="form-control dateicon" maxlength="10" minlength="10" [maxDate]="api.maxDate" name="xyz" (ngModelChange)="def($event,2)"[bsConfig]="{ isAnimated: true ,dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY'}" formControlName="abc" bsDatepicker placeholder="DD / MM / YYYY"/>
```

The above code is my ngx bootstrap date picker code and i am triggering a method via ngModelchange.

The below code represents component.ts code:

```
def(event,type){
if(type == 2){
 this.globals.stacks.controls['abc'].setValue(event);
}
}
```

Below is my global.ts code:

```
   stacks: FormGroup = this.formbuilder.group({
    abc: ['',ValideService.ghi],
    xyz: [''],
  });
```

Below is my validate Service code:

```
static ghi(control) {

        let temp = control.value;
        var minDate: any = new Date('09/01/2018');
        var maxDate: any = new Date();
        if (temp == 'undefined' || temp == null || temp == '') {
            return { 'minDatemaxDatereq': true };
        } else if (minDate > temp || maxDate < temp) {//&& 

            return { 'minDatemaxDate': true };
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Whenever i select a particular date from the date picker the `def()` 
method from the component.ts file gets triggered and it iterates for n number of times till i get maximum stack size error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just remove the `(ngModelChange)="def($event,2)"`.

Reactive Forms will handle the update of your FormControl for you.

You are creating an infinite loop by setting the FormControls value manually.
`this.globals.stacks.controls['abc'].setValue(event);` also updates your view which then triggers `(ngModelChange)="def($event,2)"` again.

Comment: I don't know if I get you right. You need to update 'xyz' if 'abc' changes? Subscribing to the valueChanges of abc would be a solution for that:
stacks.get('abc').valueChanges.subscribe(newValue => {
      stacks.get('xyz').patchValue('what ever new value you want to set');
    })

Answer (score 1):

The value of  `this.globals.stacks.controls['abc']` is already set by user from browser and you have subscribed for the `(ngModelChange)="def($event,2)"` and inside this def method you are again setting up the value manually , which will again call the ngModelChange event  and this goes on until the stack is overflow.

> What causes a stack overflow?
>
> A stack overflow occurs when there is a recursive function (a function that calls itself) >without an exit point. The browser (hosting environment) has a maximum stack call that it >can accomodate before throwing a stack error. You can get more details from this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-the-javascript-call-stack-861e41ae61d4/)

Instead you can use `valueChanges`  and do the necessary work but  remove the `(ngModelChange)` event or else it will again fall under the event loop.